# how to make my custom class to be evaluated as Falsey in Ruby

Tags: ruby

For example

```
MyClass = Class.new(Object)

a = MyClass.new
unless a
  puts "executed"
end
```

I know that `nil` and `false` are the only two values that evaluate as `false` in Ruby. But I need to evaluate the instance of `MyClass` to falsey as well. is it possible to do that?

> `nil` and `false` are the only two values that evaluate as `false` in Ruby

I'm also trying to find out where it's defined in [CRuby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby)

I know this usage is uncommon, the reason why I want to do this: https://github.com/exAspArk/batch-loader/issues/84

Comment: The problem described in the issue seems to be an object that _looks like_ `nil` without actually being `nil`.

Comment: yes. that's the expected behavior because we need to add something (lazy evaluation) on top of the underlying object. it works for most cases. but for `nil`, seems an object can't mimic `nil` being counted as false

Comment: You can't replace an object by another object in Ruby. You can only delegate its methods to the other object, which is what BatchLoader does. It won't work for `if obj` or `unless obj` or the ternary `obj ? x : y`. It will probably also fail for `case obj ; when ObjClass` because that's `ObjClass === obj` under the hood and `ObjClass` won't recognize the (virtual proxy) object as its own instance. A workaround is using `obj.itself` instead of just `obj` as it would (probably?) return the _actual_ object due to the method call.

Comment: Why would you want this in the first place? Ruby conventional style would have a method you call that returns a boolean.

Comment: @tadman IMHO, it's common usage. you wound probably write `if obj` instead of `if !!obj`. examples in Ruby Style Guide: https://rubystyle.guide/#unless-for-negatives

Comment: Sure, but it's assumed, it's fundamentally understood, that *any* object other than `nil` or `false` evaluates as true. C++ does have an "evaluate as boolean" feature, but Ruby absolutely does not.

Answer (score 3):

> how to make my custom class to be evaluated as Falsey in Ruby

You can't. `nil` and `false` are the only two values that evaluate as *falsey* in Ruby.

> But I need to evaluate the instance of `MyClass` to falsey as well. is it possible to do that?

No, it is not possible because `nil` and `false` are the only two values that evaluate as *falsey* in Ruby.

See section 6.6 *Boolean values* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html), for example:

> ## 6.6 Boolean values
>
> An object is classified into either a ***trueish object*** or a ***falseish object***.
>
> Only **false** and **nil** are falseish objects. **false** is the only instance of the class `FalseClass` (see 15.2.6), to which a *false-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.3). **nil** is the only instance of the class `NilClass` (see 15.2.4), to which a *nil-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.2).
>
> Objects other than **false** and **nil** are classified into ***trueish objects***. **true** is the only instance of the class `TrueClass` (see 15.2.5), to which a *true-expression* evaluates (see 11.5.4.8.3).

And if you check section 11.2 *Logical expressions*, 11.5.2.2 *Conditional expressions*, 11.5.2.3.2 *The `while` expression*, 11.5.2.3.3 *The `until` expression*, or the various definitions for various method contracts in the core library section of the specification such as 15.2.2.4.33 *`Module#instance_methods`*, you will find that they always only talk about *trueish* and *falseish* objects, but never allow for any protocol to either ask an object for its trueishness or falsishness or change the definition of trueish and falseish.

Unfortunately, this not proper Object-Oriented Design (in OO, it is always possible for an object to simulate another object), but there is nothing you can do about it.